# MatplotlabL : put 6 plots in one figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a data_frame, with columns: `my_time, field_A, field_B, field_C, field_D, field_E and field_F`

I am using the following code to plot `field_A vs. my_time`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

plt.plot(my_df[['my_time']], my_df[['field_A']])
plt.show()
```

`my_time` is of `datetime` unit. I then did the same thing for `field_B, field_C, field_D, field_E, field_F` and totally got 6 figures.

Is it possible to put all 6 figures as 6 subplots (2x3) of one figure? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be pretty simple. Set `my_time` to be the index and call `plot`:

```
c = ['field_A', 'field_B', ...] 
my_df.set_index('my_time')[c].plot(subplots=True) 
plt.show()
```

If you want to plot `my_time` against all other columns, this should do:

```
my_df.set_index('my_time').plot(subplots=True)
```